# Kconfig: How to prevent a specific CONFIG_* switch, when this leads to an issue?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kbuild

Is there an opposite for `depends on` in `Kconfig`? Which at least prints a warning when a specific `CONFIG_*` switch is set, which isn't compatible after the full configuration is written (`.config`) after a `make *_defconfig`?

**My current problem:**
I'm working on a new driver for the `ARMv7-M Systick timer`. There exists an old version, but this version lacks in some functionality and isn't ported to the new `U-Boot device model` (DM). When a new vendor use both driver, then this leads in an linker error.

So I want prevent with `Kconfig` to use my driver, when the old driver is selected.

Or any other suggestion how to solve this?

(This is a generic question for projects which use `Kbuild/Kconfig` as build system.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/kbuild/kconfig-language.html) states you can use `depends on <expr>`, so you can do:

```
depends on !OTHER_DRIVER
```